# Preview Mail Notification in browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

With Laravel, according [to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser), I can return a `Mailable` via a controller to display it in the browser. It helps to preview mails.

**Is there a way to preview Mail Notifications in browser?**

I tried:

```
return (new MyNotification())->toMail($some_user);
```

But it does not work:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't render [Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications). You can render [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser) that you use in `toMail()`. For example if that Mailable is called `SomeMailable`:

```
public function toMail($user)
{
    return (new SomeMailable($user))->to($user->email);
}
```

Then you can render the Mailable with:

```
return new SomeMailable($some_user);
```

Comment: It seems Laravel does not return a Mailable by default (and I'm not sure it's possible) in a notification: in my case it returns a `Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage`

Comment: @rap-2-h my point is you should forget about trying to render Notification and render Mailable class instead.

Comment: Hm OK! I will wait a bit before validating your answer, maybe someone will find a kind of way/hack for this. Anyway, Thanks! +1

Comment: @rap-2-h no problem.

Comment: Though this answer has important mentions, prefered @BenSampo's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201638/842768

Comment: Checkout @CodeSeeker's post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934386/59987607#59987607) for a great solution

Answer (score 12):

In your controller's function :

```
 $message = (new \App\Notifications\MyNotification())->toMail('example@gmail.com');    
 $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));

return $markdown->render('vendor.notifications.email', $message->data());
```

Just change the name of the notification class (and also pass arguments if necessary) and hit the url in your browser to see the preview.

Comment: nicely done. Thank you for sharing. Finally I am at rest after searching for 2 days :)

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 5.8 you can now preview it just like you would a Mailable.

```php
Route::get('mail-preview', function () {
    return (new MyNotification())->toMail($some_user);
});
```

More details here:
https://sampo.co.uk/blog/previewing-mail-notifications-in-laravel-just-got-easier

Answer (score 0):

For me, with the particular notification that I wanted to preview `toMail()` method required a `Notifiable` instance rather than just an email address, so the following code was what worked for me:

```
    $notification = new \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail();

    $user = \App\User::where('email', 'example@gmail.com')->first(); // Model with Notifiable trait

    $message = $notification->toMail($user);

    $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));

    return $markdown->render('vendor.notifications.email', $message->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Test pass after Laravel 5.6)

```php
$message = (new \App\Notifications\YourNotification()->toMail($notifiable);

return app()->make(\Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::class)->render($message->markdown, $message->data());
```