# Display Laravel Notification (MailMessage) with markdown after sent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-notification

I'm saving every email I send to an entity into the database by creating a function `storeEmail` and make an insert of `MailMessage` class into `EmailMessage` model. Everything works fine, and the main **goal** is to display the message exactly as it was, when the recipient received it and retrieve all the messages I sent as a `User`, to a page. To be much easier to retrieve a render of each specific Message in foreach loop, I think is better to fetch it from the Model.

This is my Notification class:

```
class SimpleEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $link;
    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {   
        $mail = (new MailMessage)
            ->from($this->user->email, $this->user->name)
            ->subject('My Dummy Subject')
            ->greeting('To: '.$notifiable->email)
            ->action('Action Button', url($this->link))
            ->line('Thank you for reading my message')
            ->salutation('Friendly, '.$this->user->name);

        $this->storeEmail($mail,$notifiable);
        return $mail;
    }

    public function storeEmail($mail,$notifiable){
        $email = new EmailMessage;
        $email->sender_type = 'App\User';
        $email->sender_id = $this->user->id;
        $email->mail = $mail;
        $email->save();
        $notifiable->email_messages()->save($email);
    }
}
```

***`Note:`***

1. I'm using `Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage`
2. My class extends `Illuminate\Notifications\Notification`
3. I'm saving (new MailMessage) in the $email->mail = $mail;

I tried to `dd($email->mail);` and I get this:

```
 ^ array:20 [▼
  "view" => null
  "viewData" => []
  "markdown" => "notifications::email"
  "theme" => null
  "from" => array:2 [▶]
  "replyTo" => []
  "cc" => []
  "bcc" => []
  "attachments" => []
  "rawAttachments" => []
  "priority" => null
  "callbacks" => []
  "level" => "info"
  "subject" => "My Dummy Subject"
  "greeting" => "To: Dohn John"
  "salutation" => "Friendly, Nikolas Diakosavvas"
  "introLines" => array:2 [▶]
  "outroLines" => array:1 [▶]
  "actionText" => "Action Button"
  "actionUrl" => "http://my-example-url.com ▶"
```

How can I display the Mail Notification, as it was when I sent it ? What is the optimal solution for that ?
Thanks, in advance

**EDITED**

Managed to render MailMessage using this code **works** :

```
$email = EmailMessage::first();
return (new \App\Notifications\SimpleEmail('my-link', $email->recipient->assignto))->toMail($email->recipient);
```

**But this is not exactly what I wanted**, because every time I need to find:

1. Which Notification class used on every email so I can render it.
2. Variables for each Notification class.

Comment: You can render them in the browser https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#rendering-mailables

Comment: Yes I know, but how to render the message from `EmailMessage` Model ?? Because, it is easier to access the message from the Model instead of searching the Notification class and pass the necessary variables every time.

Comment: In the docs they have `return (new App\Mail\InvoicePaid($invoice))->render();` so in your example, try just passing in `$email` or `$email->mail` in place of their $invoice.  Correct the mailable path too of cause

Comment: No, it doesn't work because `$invoice` is a variable used in `InvoicePaid` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this:

**1.** You can create a [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators).

**2.** Use [Markdown](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Mail/Markdown.html)'s `render` method.

**3.** Pass in `render` method the **mail's markdown** you saved in `storeEmail`.

You can see an example above :

```
use \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;

public function getRenderAttribute(){
    $markdown = new Markdown(view());
    return $markdown->render($this->mail['markdown'], $this->mail);
}
```